# How soon do I have to change difficulty levels to get the Mass Effect 3 insanity award?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I just started the game and it never game me an option to change the difficulty like in Mass Effect 2.

The first thing I did after cinematic start finished, was change the difficulty from normal to insanity. Is there a period where I have time to change it before it takes hold, or am I now doomed to not getting the award for playing 1 second on normal?

It's on Insanity now and will remain so till end of game.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be fine. As shown [here](http://www.xbox360achievements.org/game/mass-effect-3/achievements/), the description for the Insanity achievement is

> Finish the game on Insanity without changing difficulty **after leaving Earth.**

(bold mine)

So, as long as you changed the difficulty while you were still on Earth (which you said you did), you will get the achievement when you beat the game.

Comment: Awesome thanks. Glad I checked the difficulty at the start :)

Comment: Disappointing ending much? Paragon was renegade and vise versa, and the only difference really was the colour beam sent out. >.<

Comment: Yes, most of us agreed that the ending was a disappointment. Luckily, EA will be releasing free DLC that will extend the ending, which may alleviate some of that disappointment. What did you mean by "Paragon was renegade and vise versa"?

Comment: The paragon ending was the choice of the illusive man. Where as the renegade was the choice of the captain Anderson. Plus there is nothing renegade about destroying a race that is/has wiped out thousands of races. IMO destroying the reapers to save all the races was paragon. Letting them live, and being in control of a super race is renegade, Being all powerful.. Power hungry.